# Where should I store a Computer wide license/Computer wide settings?

Tags: c#, windows-7, application-settings

I've been looking for all most a day now. Is there any place to store a Computer-wide license. I don't want to use the Registry, so don't suggest that.

This license will be installed during the program's runtime, so what I need is a place to store computer wide settings that can have read/write access without running as Admin.

I've looked online, and Microsoft, in their infinite 'wisdom' for security apparently locked down all methods of saving application wide settings.

Comment: A non admin can only write where allowed to. This means by default: the HKCU portion of the registry),  "documents and settings" (XP) or "users" (Vista/7) and below, and that's about it. Not computer wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 7 I use the hidden ProgramData folder.  I have just checked and it is available to users, they just can't see it by default.

I normally use it for storing .ini files in for applications.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Slotty. From your advice, I went back trying to save to the ProgramData folder. I was getting an exception, but it was because the directory didn't exist yet and I was using the File.WriteAllBytes method which won't automatically create the directory for you...